# Mggraph filter showing different results for the same basetype

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MG graph command, Get-MgGroup with Filter to get Onprem groups created in last 24 hours. Strage that the filter works fine with OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime but not with CreatedDateTime, even though the type is same for both.

```
$now = Get-Date

# Subtract 24 hours from the current date and time**
$Time = $now.AddHours(-24)

# Convert the date and time to ISO 8601 format
$TimeISO = $Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

$X = Get-MgGroup -Filter "OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl
$Y= Get-MgGroup -Filter "CreatedDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl
```

$X gets the result but $y throws an error

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-MgGroup -Filter "CreatedDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl 
Get-MgGroup : Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 
'createdDateTime' of resource 'Group'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MgGroup -Filter "CreatedDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ ConsistencyLe...ndProperty =  }:<>f__Anonym 
   ousType84`9) [Get-MgGroup_List], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Request_UnsupportedQuery,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetM 
   gGroup_List

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $X = Get-MgGroup -Filter "OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime ge $TimeISO"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $X.OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime.GetType()
$X.CreatedDateTime.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                            
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType                    
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType                    



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $TimeISO
2023-07-26T17:04:29Z
```

Answer (score 1):

I have below **on-prem groups** existing in my Azure AD tenant:

[image]

When I ran same script as you in my environment to get Onprem groups created in last 24 hours, I got **same error** like below:

```
$now = Get-Date

# Subtract 24 hours from the current date and time**
$Time = $now.AddHours(-24)

# Convert the date and time to ISO 8601 format
$TimeISO = $Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

$X = Get-MgGroup -Filter "OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl
$Y= Get-MgGroup -Filter "CreatedDateTime ge $TimeISO"| fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, not all group properties are supported for filtering query in which `createdDateTime`  is one of them. You can check the list of group properties that support **$filter** from this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

When I tried to filter the groups with `OnPremisesLastSyncDateTime`, I got the groups successfully as that property supports **$filter**.

[image]

Alternatively, you can retrieve **all on-prem groups** and then filter them with `createdDateTime`  property using below script:

```
$now = Get-Date
$Time = $now.AddHours(-24)
$TimeISO = $Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

# Retrieve all on-premises groups 
$OnPremGroups = Get-MgGroup -Filter "OnPremisesSyncEnabled eq true"

$filteredOnPremGroups = $OnPremGroups | Where-Object { $_.CreatedDateTime -ge $TimeISO }
$filteredOnPremGroups
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Filter Groups by createdDateTime - Microsoft Q&A by **CarlZhao-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/887837/filter-groups-by-createddatetime)